# Is flat spacetime just something with constant metric components from point to point?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Is flat spacetime just something with constant metric components from point to point so that the derivatives of $g_{ij}$ with respect to the coordinates of spacetime vanish?

Comment: In spherical polar coordinates does Minkowski spacetime have a constant metric?

Comment: Great, thanks.  The counterexample answers the question

Comment: You are almost right. The statement is as follows. A spacetime is flat if and only if there exists a coordinate frame such that the coefficients of the metric are constant. This means that there has to  exists at least one such coordinate frame. Notice that this does not mean that a spacetime is flat if and only if the coefficients of the metric are constant. It could be that you just did not consider the coordinates in which the metric components are constant. The more rigorous way is to check whether the Riemann tensor is the zero tensor.

Comment: It depends upon whether you're measuring the intrinsic or extrinsic curvature. For instance, the surface of the earth is extrinsically curved since it's embedded in a submanifold of a flat manifold $\mathbb{R}^3$. See @Mathphysmeister comment.

Answer (score 2):

No. Minkowski spacetime in spherical polar coordinates does not have a constant metric.

Answer (score 2):

> Is flat spacetime just something with a metric constant from point to point so that the derivatives of  with respect to the coordinates of spacetime vanish

As @G. Smith correctly answered the derivatives of the metric with respect to the coordinates does not vanish for all coordinate systems even in flat spacetime. However, there is a related concept that may be of more interest to you. Specifically, the Lie derivative.

The Lie derivative gives a coordinate independent measure of the change of a tensor along a particular flow. A Killing vector is a flow along which the Lie derivative is zero. For example, the Schwarzschild spacetime has spherical symmetry, so there are flows which represent rotations and these flows are Killing vectors.

Minkowski spacetime has 10 Killing vector flows. Four represent spacetime translations, three represent spatial rotations, and three represent boosts. Any spacetime with those Killing vectors is flat, and I believe that is the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a flat space-time all components of the Riemann tensor are zero. In $R^{3}$ the metric is $diag(1,1,1)$ and all the components of the Riemann tensor are zero. In spherical polar co-ordinates(again in $R^{3}$) the metric is $diag(1,r^{2},r^{2}sin^{2}\theta)$ and still the components of the Riemann tensor are all zero. So a flat spacetime is a spacetime with a vanishing Riemann tensor.

Comment: The metric is not necessarily diagonal, and saying it is unitary , which is a condition on *complex* matrices, is confusing.

Comment: Ok, i'll edit my answer then!